# How do I replay my main function? (Read description, hard to word title)

Tags: c++, loops

I apologize in advance for the misleading title, I'm not really sure how to phrase my question without more room. I'll start with showing you my main function.

```
int main() {
    int input;
    List List;
    cout << "Press '1' to add a node" << endl;
    cout << "Press '2' to view the list of nodes" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    if (input == 1) {
    List.addNode();
    }
    else if (input == 2) {
    List.PrintList();
    }    
}
```

So as you can see by the nature of the main function, the user will want to input more than 1 node ( input 1 ). As it stands now, if I input a node, the program ends. In a perfect program, I would like to be able to allow the user to input as many data points as they would like and also be able to print them out. Both functions are basically useless right now since more than one data point is need as well as the user will want to reprint the points they entered.

With the description out of the way: My question is just how do I get the main function to replay itself? Thanks for any help in advance guys.

Comment: ***My question is just how do I get the main function to replay itself?*** Use a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you really want is a shift that happens all the time in computer science. You'll need to rework your code a little, you've effectively out-lived your main function. Time to re-write your code.

```
 int new_function() {
     int input;
     ... // Do the rest of your function here
 }

 int main() {
     int i;
     for (i=0; i < XXX; i++) {
         new_function();
     }
 }
```

Depending on how your program fully develops, you may want to loop in main, or you might want to do the loop in your new function or whatever. That part of your architecture you'll have to decide based on your functionality.

Good luck!

Comment: Best answer so far because it teaches a beginner *not* to use spaghetti code. +1

Comment: Of course, in C++, you want to limit `i`'s scope to the loop, i.e. `(for int i = 0, i < XXX; i++)`.

Comment: I'm marking this answer as correct, although what I ended up doing is using a while loop inside new_function() and just calling that function in main, no for loop. credits to you and donken for this. I wish I could mark two answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just shove it in a while loop?

```
int main() {
   int input = 0;
   List nodeList;

   /*Loop till user chooses to exit.*/
   while(input != 3)
   {
      /*Display options for user and take output.*/
      cout << "Press '1' to add a node" << endl;
      cout << "Press '2' to view the list of nodes" << endl;
      cout << "Press '3' to exit" << endl;
      cin >> input;

      /*Add a node to list.*/
      if (input == 1) {
          nodeList.addNode();
      }

      /*Display node list.*/
      else if (input == 2) {
          nodeList.PrintList();
      } 

      /*Exit program.*/
      else if (input == 3) {
          return 0;
      }

      /*Re-prompt user to input again.*/
      else {
         cout << "Invalid input.. try again." << endl;
      }
   }
   /*Won't reach.*/
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if I did a while look inside of another function and just bumped that function into the main function? Would that work the same so to not clutter up main?

Comment: Definitely! That's exactly what I would do. It seemed like you had your heart set on putting it in the main though so I didn't suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

A *for* loop will repeat as many times as you wish.

```
int i=0;
for (i=0;i<10;i++){
   // do something 10 times
}
```

A while loop is great too as noted by the other answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a do-while loop with an additional cout<<"press 3 for exit". Enclose all the couts, if-else in the do-while to be able to loop it until users hits 3. In the while condition , set while(input!=3).